# Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_DDA_NOT_ACCEPTED

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, google-developers-console

[I meet this issue "Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_DDA_NOT_ACCEPTED" when trying to upload my file aab, pls help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug.

The message should read *"The account owner must accept the Developer Distribution Agreement before you can publish your application"*

Ask the owner of the account to log in and they should be prompted to accept the DDA. After that, you should be able to release.